# Checking message.content for certain text

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a multiple-choice trivia background task. I'm trying to await client.wait_for_message only for either the correct answer or the incorrect choices. I'm checking message.content but I'm missing something because no matter what anyone types, it says "incorrect answer" UNLESS it's the correct answer. If someone types something other than the incorrect answer or correct answer then I want it to ignore their text.

```
async def trivia_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel("123456778999533")
    triviamonies = random.randint(1250, 2550)
    while not client.is_closed:
        await client.send_message(channel, '**Category**: {}\n**Difficulty**: {}\n\n{}\n\n**Potential Answers:**\n{}'.format(category, formatdiff, formatquestion, '\n'.join(tup)))
        winner = ''
        def check(m):
            return m.content.lower() == formatanswer.lower() and m.content.lower() != incorrectanswer1 or incorrectanswer2 or incorrectanswer3
        while winner == '':
            answerid = await client.wait_for_message(timeout=420, channel=channel, check=check)
            if answerid is None:
                winner = 1
                await client.delete_message(questionsend)
                await client.send_message(channel, 'No one answered correctly! The answer was {}'.format(formatanswer))
                await asyncio.sleep(840)
            elif get_triviaguessesTaken(answerid.author) < 1 and answerid.content.lower() == formatanswer.lower():
                winner = 1
                await client.delete_message(questionsend)
                await client.send_message(channel, '**{}** is correct!\n{} earns **${:,}** !'.format(formatanswer, answerid.author.mention, triviamonies))
                add_dollars(answerid.author, triviamonies)
                add_trivias(answerid.author, 1)
                await asyncio.sleep(900)
            elif get_triviaguessesTaken(answerid.author) < 1 and answerid.content.lower() == incorrectanswer1 or incorrectanswer2 or incorrectanswer3:
                await client.send_message(channel, '**{}** that is incorrect! Please try again on the next trivia question'.format(answerid.author.mention))
                add_triviaguessesTaken(answerid.author, 1)
            elif get_triviaguessesTaken(answerid.author) > 0 and answerid.content.lower() == incorrectanswer1 or incorrectanswer2 or incorrectanswer3:
                await client.send_message(channel, '{} you have already tried to guess this trivia question. Try again on the next one!'.format(answerid.author.mention))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Discord.py Version:

From the looks of your code, you're still using the async version of d.py (v0.16.12), and you haven't moved to the more up-to-date and stable [rewrite version of d.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#).

I can highly recommend running `pip install --upgrade discord.py` for the most recent stable version. Make sure you do this and rewrite your code sooner rather than later, as it'll be less of a pain when you have less code to work with.

## [`Wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) usage in rewrite:

The docs use an example in an [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event, but I'll make an example here to suit your case with a command instead, so you have both ways available to you and can mix-and-match:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["trivia"])
async def starttrivia(ctx):
    answers = ["paris", "london", "oslo"]
    await ctx.send(f"What's the capital of France?\n\n*Potential answers:*\n{', '.join(answers)}")
    correct = False
    
    def check(m):
        for a in answers:
            if a in m.content.lower():
                return True

    while not correct:
        try:    
            reply = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
            if "paris" in reply.content.lower():
                await ctx.send(f"Correct! {reply.author.mention} got the right answer!")
                correct = True
            else:
                await ctx.send("Incorrect, try again!")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError: # exception thrown when no reply is sent in time
            await ctx.send("Nobody guessed for 30 seconds! The answer was: Paris")
            break
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. I added the check you put in there which makes sense but added .lower() to a and it works flawlessly with if/else statements

Comment: @hardestchat Glad to hear you got it working! If you're unsure about anything while [migrating to rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), don't be afraid to ask for help! Good luck :)